# Interaction between type classes and auto tactic

Tags: coq, ltac

Consider this simple development. I have two trivial data types:

```
Inductive A :=
| A1
| A2.

Inductive B :=
| B1 : A -> B
| B2.
```

Now I introduce a concept of relation and define ordering on data types `A` and `B` expressed as an inductive data type:

```
Definition relation (X : Type) := X -> X -> Prop.

Reserved Notation "a1 '<=A' a2" (at level 70).

Inductive AOrd : relation A :=
| A1_Ord : A1 <=A A1
| A2_Ord : A2 <=A A2
| A1_A2  : A1 <=A A2
where "a1 '<=A' a2" := (AOrd a1 a2).

Reserved Notation "b1 '<=B' b2" (at level 70).

Inductive BOrd : relation B :=
| B1_Ord : forall a1 a2,
    a1 <=A a2 -> B1 a1 <=B B1 a2
| B2_Ord :
    B2 <=B B2
| B1_B2  : forall a,
    B1 a <=B B2
where "b1 '<=B' b2" := (BOrd b1 b2).
```

Finally, I introduce a concept of reflexivity and prove that both of my relations are reflexive:

```
Definition reflexive {X : Type} (R : relation X) :=
  forall a : X, R a a.

Hint Constructors AOrd BOrd.

Theorem AOrd_reflexive : reflexive AOrd.
Proof.
  intro a. induction a; auto.
Qed.

Hint Resolve AOrd_reflexive.

Theorem BOrd_reflexive : reflexive BOrd.
Proof.
  intro b. induction b; auto.
Qed.
```

Both proofs are finished with `auto` tactic, with the first proof crucially relying on `Hint Constructors` and the second one additionally on `Hint Resolve AOrd_reflexive` being added to hint database.

An ugly thing about the code above is having a separate notation for ordering relation for `A` and `B` data types. I'd like to be able to uniformly use `<=` everywhere. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057494/1273482) provides a solution to the problem: use type classes. So I introduce a type class for ordering and redefine my ordering relations to use this new notation:

```
Class OrderR (T : Type) := orderR : relation T.
Notation "x '<=' y" := (orderR x y) (at level 70).

Inductive AOrd : OrderR A :=
| A1_Ord : A1 <= A1
| A2_Ord : A2 <= A2
| A1_A2  : A1 <= A2.

Inductive BOrd `{OrderR A} : OrderR B :=
| B1_Ord : forall a1 a2,
    a1 <= a2 -> B1 a1 <= B1 a2
| B2_Ord :
    B2 <= B2
| B1_B2  : forall a,
    B1 a <= B2.

Hint Constructors AOrd BOrd.
```

But now proof automation breaks! For example:

```
Theorem AOrd_reflexive : reflexive AOrd.
Proof.
  intro a. induction a.
```

leaves me with a goal:

```
2 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID 32)

  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  AOrd A1 A1
```

that `auto` no longer solves despite `AOrd` constructors being in hint database. I can solve the goal with `constructor` though:

```
Theorem AOrd_reflexive : reflexive AOrd.
Proof.
  intro a. induction a; constructor.
Qed.
```

More problems arise in second proof. After doing:

```
Theorem BOrd_reflexive `{OrderR A} : reflexive BOrd.
Proof.
  intro b. induction b. constructor.
```

I am left with goal:

```
2 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID 40)

  H : OrderR A
  a : A
  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  a <= a
```

Again, `auto` no longer solves this goal. Even `apply AOrd_reflexive` does not work.

My question is: is it possible to have a uniform notation by relying on type classes and maintain benefits of proof automation? Or is there a different solution to having a uniform notation for various data types.

Comment: Hey Jan, not sure if that solves your particular issue, but there is a `auto with typeclass_instances.` tactic variation to make sure type class instances participate in the `auto` search.

Comment: @Ptival, I'm afraid this does not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that does not involve typeclasses is to take advantage of the scope mechanism of Coq.

```
Inductive A :=
| A1
| A2.

Inductive B :=
| B1 : A -> B
| B2.

Definition relation (X : Type) := X -> X -> Prop.

Reserved Notation "a1 '<=' a2" (at level 70).

Inductive AOrd : relation A :=
| A1_Ord : A1 <= A1
| A2_Ord : A2 <= A2
| A1_A2  : A1 <= A2
where "a1 '<=' a2" := (AOrd a1 a2) : a_scope.

Delimit Scope a_scope with a.

Inductive BOrd : relation B :=
| B1_Ord : forall a1 a2,
    (a1 <= a2)%a -> B1 a1 <= B1 a2
| B2_Ord :
    B2 <= B2
| B1_B2  : forall a,
    B1 a <= B2
where "b1 '<=' b2" := (BOrd b1 b2) : b_scope.

Delimit Scope b_scope with b.

Definition reflexive {X : Type} (R : relation X) :=
  forall a : X, R a a.

Hint Constructors AOrd BOrd.

Theorem AOrd_reflexive : reflexive AOrd.
Proof.
  intro a. induction a; auto.
Qed.

Hint Resolve AOrd_reflexive.

Theorem BOrd_reflexive : reflexive BOrd.
Proof.
  intro b. induction b; auto.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not a perfect solution but it looks like an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your hints are set to trigger on, e.g., `@orderR _ AOrd A1 A2`, not `AOrd A1 A2`.  So the automation never sees the pattern it's looking for, and never triggers the hints.  Here are two solutions:

(1) You can adjust the type of your constructors when adding them to the hint database, so that they trigger when you want them to:

```
Hint Resolve (A1_Ord : AOrd _ _) (A2_Ord : AOrd _ _) (A1_A2 : AOrd _ _).
Hint Resolve (@B1_Ord : forall H a1 a2, _ -> BOrd _ _)
     (@B2_Ord : forall H, BOrd _ _)
     (@B1_B2 : forall H a, BOrd _ _).
```

(2) You can define "folding" lemmas that convert the types, and add those to the database:

```
Definition fold_AOrd a1 a2 (v : a1 <= a2) : AOrd a1 a2 := v.
Definition fold_BOrd `{OrderR A} (a1 a2 : B) (v : a1 <= a2) : BOrd a1 a2 := v.
Hint Resolve fold_AOrd fold_BOrd.
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm afraid your solution does not work for me. Folding lemmas don't seem to change anything. Adjusting type of constructors works when proving `AOrd_reflexive` but in the proof of `BOrd_reflexive` it is still not possible to prove `a <= a` from `AOrd_reflexive`.